# Asp.net Routes with two routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two route with same signature but only the parameter names are different how to fix this issue.
Following is my code

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "DefaultRoute2",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{formSubmissionId}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", formSubmissionId = "formSubmissionId" }
 );
```

Comment: How would this work? The URL `/controller1/action1/12` in what route would it be mapped?

Comment: What is the point of the second route?

Comment: what is exactly what needs to be fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i fix this issue as

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultActivity",
            url: "{controller}/LoadActivity/{formSubmissionId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "{controller}", action = "LoadActivity", formSubmissionId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

this is work around of my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The routes are meant to accept different URL structures. Both of your routes have same structure, so the first one will always match, and the second will never be tested.

Instead of using a different route, in `/Employee/Index` you should just use the parameter `id`.

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        string formSubmissionId = id;
    }
}
```

The URL for that action would be the same that (I believe) you wanted to achieve with the second route: `Employee/Index/id`

**UPDATE**

I've just realized. If you only need the parameter `formSubmissionId` for the action `/Employee/Index` you could do this:

```
// Note the order of the routes:
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "DefaultRoute2",
     url: "Employee/Index/{formSubmissionId}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", formSubmissionId = "formSubmissionId" }
 );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string formSubmissionId)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i have round about 30 Controller like Employee1,Employee2,....Employee30 these Controller Action method have parameter formSubmissionId and 10 other controller which actionMethod parameter is id so i want a generic route that map my controller .

Comment: Unless you have some way to identify (via regex) which controllers or actions use each parameter, there is no way to achieve what you want.